# "invalid default value" with lxml and ATTLIST tag

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I'm trying to parse a XML file (provided by `opdis`) with `lxml` ; it fails at this line :

`<!ATTLIST operand type (target|src|dest) "">`

It says : `Attribute operand of type: invalid default value`

The problem comes from the `""` at the end of the tag. If I fill it with something like `"nothing"`, it works fine. `lxml` just doesn't like the empty string.

The thing is that I can't edit the XML, it has to be generated dynamically by `opdis`, so I must find a way to make `lxml` ignore this error.

Here is the code :

```
xml = subprocess.Popen(["opdis", "-f", "xml", "-E", "/home/ubuntu/workspace/testbinaries/bin/acc"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read();
tree = etree.fromstring(xml); #FAIL!
```

Do you have any clue ?

Comment: please post the code and show which `lxml` function you are using/calling

Comment: here it is, i grabbed the xml by launching `opdis` by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line

```
<!ATTLIST operand type (target|src|dest) "">
```

is a [DTD attribute declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttlistDecl) of the `operand` attribute. According to the specification:

```
AttlistDecl    ::=      '<!ATTLIST' S Name AttDef* S? '>'
AttDef         ::=      S Name S AttType S DefaultDecl
```

The empty string corresponds to `DefaultDecl`, the default value of the attribute (and `S` corresponds to a white space).

The [default value](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-DefaultDecl) should be define with:

```
DefaultDecl    ::=      '#REQUIRED' | '#IMPLIED'
            | (('#FIXED' S)? AttValue)  [VC: Required Attribute]
            [VC: Attribute Default Value Syntactically Correct]
            [WFC: No < in Attribute Values]
            [VC: Fixed Attribute Default]
            [WFC: No External Entity References]
```

So it cannot be an empty string, lxml is doing his job right.

You have to submit a new issue to the opdis mailing list. You can also set yourself in your code the value `#REQUIRED` or `#IMPLIED` to correct the problem:

```
xml  = subprocess.Popen(["opdis", "-f", "xml", "-E", "/home/ubuntu/workspace/testbinaries/bin/acc"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read();
xml  = xml.replace("\"\"","#REQUIRED")
tree = etree.fromstring(xml); #OK
```